# Consuming kafka messages in large batches

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My goal is to consume messages from kafka in a fairly large batches. For example, I'd like to get a batch of approx 10000 records or if there're not enough of them get a batch every 20 seconds.

Here are the settings I try:

```
            max.poll.records=10000,
            fetch.max.wait.ms=20000,
            fetch.min.bytes=10000,
            fetch.max.bytes=1000000,
            max.partition.fetch.bytes=1000000,
            max.message.bytes=100000000
```

On a test topic I have 3 partitions with 10 existing small records in each of them. When I start a consumer with the above parameters I have a weird behavior:

I get a set of small batches (one per partition) with < 10 records on startup. Then there is idle interval of 20 seconds (fetch.max.wait.ms!) and afterwards I get set of batches with the rest of values.

How come this happens? I was expecting to read all existing records in one batch. Or at least three batches (one per partition). It looks like I miss something, is specified behavior even achievable?

Comment: The max.poll.records is an upper bound on the limit that will be polled, it won't wait for that many records to accumulate on the topic. You can instead pause and resume a consumer manually, and in between sleep a thread for 20 seconds, though, if you have an active, high throughput producer, then that'll cause significantly rising consumer lag, IMO